IntProperty in panel without key/animatable (dot) icon
Developing an addon for blender.
how can I remove the animate(keyable) symbol right here as arrow2 shows ?
I have another addon that somehow IntProperty (as arrow1 shows) does not have that animate key button. 
both are same. one has keyable icon that I don't want other already doesn't have.
I want Padding IntProperty without keyable/animatable (dot icon)
but how?


Linked Q&A is the inverse of your question but I think you can manage to set it to False instead of True ;) Cheers
